# EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set()

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am creating nodes programmatically. I Have written following code,

```
$e = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'some_node'));
// Specify the author.
$e->uid = 1;
// Create a Entity Wrapper of that new Entity.
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $e);

// Specify the title.
$entity->title = 'Some Title';
$entity->body = 'abc';
$entity->save();
```

On giving value to body i am getting following error. Commenting body it works fine

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it
>   matches the required data type and format. in
>   EntityMetadataWrapper->set()

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Body is a Field API field and not a native PHP variable, therefore you cannot assign values to it like that. Instead, you would need to pass an array with the following keys:

```
$entity->body->set(array(
  'value' => 'This is the body',
  'summary' => 'This is the summary',
  'format' => 'full_html',
));
```

If you wish to set the value for a specific language, you call prior to set:

```
$entity->language(LANGUAGE_NONE); // or 'en' or whatever
```

More on wrappers: https://drupal.org/node/1021556

Comment: Sorry its not working i am getting following error after using your code Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityStructureWrapper as array in

Comment: Right, it's a wrapper, my bad. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code

```
$entity->body->set(array('value' => "abc"));
```

Comment: Thanks any idea how can i define input format so that it could accept html tags?